# Rapidly moving particles during fermentation?

Tags: fermentation, hops

I'm about 24 hours into fermenting my first IPA in a carboy using Safale-04.  The fermentation is going well but I noticed small particles floating around in all directions.  My best guess is that these are either clumps of yeast or hop particles (maybe both?) that are being moved around by the CO<sub>2</sub> being generated by fermentation.

It might be hard to see but they are the small areas in this picture and they move around almost as fast as I would expect in boiling water:

[image: Small lighter clumps throughout beer]

Is this fairly normal for fermentation with a highly flocculative yeast or a larger amount of hops?  Or maybe this just a really aggressive fermentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a totally normal active fermentation.  It won't be flocculated yeast at this point, so much as break protein and hop material.

Comment: Two totally normal and fun to watch too sometimes.

Comment: The mechanics of fermentation is truly a rabbit hole. I love the simplicity of  jsled's answer here for where it appears you are in brewing. I can only suggest to you what I did then, and still do now, get as close as your eyes will let you and watch the magic you have created.